# How to exclude Eclipse plugin library jars from Tomcat classpath

Tags: eclipse

I have a Spring MVC project that uses Maven imported into Eclipse Kepler SR1 JEE and deployed to Tomcat 7 within Eclipse. Everything was fine until I recently added elasticsearch as a dependency to the Maven pom file and now when I start Tomcat I get an exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

Launching the server in verbose mode, I see that its because the servlet API is now being loaded from 2 places:
the Tomcat installation folder where it normally comes from

```
Loaded javax.servlet.Servlet from file:/C:/ProgramFiles/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

but also from one of the Eclipse plugins (Groovy) I have installed

```
Loaded javax.servlet.Servlet from file:/C:/ProgramFiles/eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_1.8.6.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. If I rename the servlet jar file in the plugin's lib folder (i.e. change the extension from .jar to something else so that its not recognized), Tomcat starts up without an exception but that's a hack and so I'd like to know what the cause is and if I'm missing some configuration to exclude plugin library jars from the Tomcat classpath.

Thanks.

Comment: as you seem to be using maven then in your maven dependencies you can say that the jar is for compile only.  But I am not so sure this is your problem.

Comment: The servlet dependency in the pom is set to 'compile'. I don't think its a Maven setup issue but I mentioned the Maven setup in case it could somehow be related to the m2e plugin. I have many 3rd party libraries in the project that have been working fine, I don't know why elasticsearch makes this happen. Elasticsearch does support a Groovy API but I am not including that dependency (its a separate jar) so I don't even see a connection.

Comment: Take a look at the classpath of the project from within eclipse and make sure only the required libraries are there. I am guessing maybe the Groovy plugin is also set inside the class-path.

Comment: I went to "Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries" and apart from the JRE jars, all the others are from my local maven repository folder. I do have the groovy-all jar as a dependency (also from the maven repository folder) but I've had that for a long time